# PyGame collide_rect is detecting a non-existent collision

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I'm still pretty new to pygame, and coding in general. I'm making a game that requires collision detection, and I seem to be having a problem with it. Every time I run my program, it detects non-existent collisions. Here are some snippets from my code:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.right = False
        self.left = False
        self.up = False
        self.down = False
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((50,50))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

    def collision_test(self):
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, block1):
            print("a collision is detected")
```

The above is my player class.

```
class Block1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((self.width,self.height))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (150,150,150), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
```

And that's my class for the obstacle that my player is supposed to collide with. I'm running a print command in the collision detection for debugging. Like I said, it just constantly prints the message I gave it, even when they aren't colliding. There are no error messages though. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

I changed the collision_test method and added the block1 argument. Now it is this:

```
    def collision_test(self, block1):
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, block1):
            print("a collision is detected")
```

My player and block1 sprites are initiated just before the mainloop, and look like this:

```
player = Player(50,50,50,50)
block1 = Block1(200, 200, 100, 100)
```

I am calling the function, collision_test, at the end of the mainloop. In case you need it, here is my full code: https://pastebin.com/LTQdLMuV

Comment: Hello! Your `collision_test(self)` method does not take any `block1` argument. Where that `block1` comes from? Where in the code do you call this function? Please add the portion of code where you instatiate objects from your classes and use them too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Just edited my post. Like I said, I'm new to coding and therefore new to stackoverflow, so I'm not sure if you get notified when I edit.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I think I found the problem. I'll write it in an answer

Answer (score 4):

What happens is that you forgot to update the position of the rectangles of your objects.

From [pygame docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect):

> get_rect()
> get the rectangular area of the Surface
> get_rect(**kwargs)-> Rect
> Returns a new rectangle covering the entire surface. **This rectangle will always start at 0, 0 with a width. and height the same size as the image.**

In both classes `Player` and `Block1` you have a line:

```
self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
```

To use `colliderect()` the `rect` attribute must be updated to the position (in pixels) of the image on the screen, otherwise there is a mismatch between the coordinates used by your `draw()` method and the rectangle used to check the collisions. Do instead:

```
self.rect = self.surf.get_rect().move(x, y)
```

so that, when the object is created, the `rect` attribute corresponds to the real position of the object on the screen.

Remember to update the position of `player.rect` when you move the player square. Edit your `move_player()` function too, for example by adding:

```
player.rect.x = player.x
player.rect.y = player.y
```

So that `rect` corresponds on what you have on the screen.

#### EDIT after comments

If your goal is *how to preveent orverlapping between surfaces*, it's more complicated. Detecting the collision is only part of the process. The full steps are:

- move the player object.
- detecting not only if there is a collision, but also the sides which collided.
- once the side is detected, move back the player object on that axis.
- redraw.

Comment: That was the problem, thank you! But I guess I wasn't quite specific enough in the question... It is now detecting collisions as it should, but how can I use that so my player cannot overlap into block1? I don't know how to go about making it into an obstacle that my player can't go through. I think I might need a way of testing what side the player is overlapping on so I can immediately move the player back out of block1.

Comment: That is a whole different problem, probably too broad for stackoverflow. I'm going to add some tips in the answer,

Comment: Try to implement those steps, and if you encounter some difficulty, you can come back with a question on that specific point.

Comment: Ok, I think I might be able to logic my way through it. Thanks